# MySQL: Most efficient way to check if an entry has a value in a comma-separated field?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table *user* and need to check which entries inside it contain a given value inside their *classes* field, which is I currently have as a comma separated list of all the classes they belong to.

My best idea is to get ever user, separate their *classes* field into an array and cycle through that to check if there is a match, but especially as the list of users gets bigger that would be horribly inefficient.

So I was wondering if there is either a better way to find a match inside a list containing comma separated values, or if there's just a better way to store these classes (the number of classes isn't fixed).

Comment: No, your best solution is to structure your data correctly for a relational database.  That means having a junction table, with one row per user and per class.  Storing lists in comma separated string fields is *not* the best solution.

Comment: Yes, the junction table does sound like the best solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, then you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

> FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>   Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL. This function does not work
>   properly if the first argument contains a comma (“,”) character.

So you could do a query like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('class to search', class_list);
```